# How to use Google Maps Libraries in Ruby?

Tags: javascript, ruby, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries 
In the documentation,its given that java-script code for maps API can be loaded via this bootstrap URL. My application works on Ruby. But I want to use the libraries listed in the above link. Can someone please tell me how to use these java objects/methods in Ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby in general is a server-side language. It is run and interpreted on the server itself. The Google Javascript libraries run in the browser. They are interpreted on the client side. Therefore you cannot directly use the Javascript libraries in Ruby.

However if your Ruby app generates HTML pages, you can use the Google libraries in the HTML templates and show maps etc.